# Use the Leading Coefficients Test to describe the left-hand and right-hand behavior of the graph $f(x)=-\dfrac{x^3}{2}-2x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on how to do this problem and I don't know how to get the answer.

$$f(x)=-\frac{x^3}{2}-2x$$

Comment: Use the Leading Coefficients Test to describe the left-hand and right-hand behaviorof the graph: f(x)=-1/2x^3-2x. Tell me if you need me to write it more neatly! It's hard trying to write it without any keyboard calculator of some sort!

Comment: it should be f(x)=-1/2 and the x^3 should be beside that fraction, after that, then you did it perfectly!

Comment: Note that: $-\dfrac{1}{2}x^3= -\dfrac{x^3}{2}$

Comment: I see! That's the fraction sir, can you please show me the steps etc? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the leading coefficient is $-\dfrac{1}{2} < 0$ which means that the end-behavior of $f(x)$ is going to mimic a negative cubic $-x^3$. This means when $x$ is sufficiently large, $f(x) \approx -x^3$, and you know well the graph of $y = -x^3$. This shows when $x$ is big enough in size ( positive or negative ) its graph is going to look like the graph of $y = -x^3$.